# Android Plus & Minus buttons clicked value display in multiple rows not working correctly in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm a beginner in android development.I have two buttons and TextView in a linear layout. When i click plus button value increase for multiple row items and same for minus button clicking time.Also when I scrolling clicked value move to next position.Can you please help me how to fix the bugs.Below i wrote i my code.[Listview item image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wk48h.jpg)

ListViewAdapter.java

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public Context context;
public LayoutInflater inflater;
public ArrayList<JSONObject> al = null;

public ItemListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<JSONObject> itemListAl) {

    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.al = itemListAl;
    
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return al.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return al.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}




class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtListItems;
    ImageView imgArrow;
    TextView qtyview;
    TextView qtyvalue;
    ImageButton increment;
    ImageButton decrement;


    RelativeLayout rootLayout;


}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int type = getItemViewType(position);

    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        //row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_rowview_plus, parent, false);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.items_rowview_plus,parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtListItems = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_listItems);
        holder.imgArrow = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_arrow);
        holder.qtyview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty_view);
        holder.qtyvalue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty_value);
        holder.increment = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.increment_btn);
        holder.decrement = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.decrement_btn);
        holder.rootLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.root_RelativeLayout);
        holder.increment.setTag(holder);
        holder.decrement.setTag(holder);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }
   else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    try {
        if(position==0){
            //convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_top);
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_header);

        }
        else if(position==al.size()-1){
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_bottom);
        }

        else{
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_middle);
        }
    
        if(position == 0){
            
            holder.txtListItems.setText(al.get(position).get("ListviewHeader").toString());
            holder.imgArrow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.qtyvalue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.qtyview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.increment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.decrement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_top);
            holder.txtListItems.setEnabled(false);
            holder.txtListItems.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            //holder.rootLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.dark_blue);
            
        }

        else{
        holder.txtListItems.setText(al.get(position).get("c_field_name").toString());
        holder.imgArrow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.qtyvalue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.qtyview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.increment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.decrement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.txtListItems.setEnabled(true);

        holder.txtListItems.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.Black));
        
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    holder.rootLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!al.get(position).isNull("c_field_name")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ItemDetailsActivity.class);
                            
            try {


                SharedData.sharedInstance().editItemDetails=false;
                SharedData.sharedInstance().ListId = al.get(position).getString("c_id").toString();
                Log.v("cid",SharedData.sharedInstance().ListId);
                SharedData.sharedInstance().ListName = al.get(position).get("c_field_name").toString();
                Log.v("ListName",SharedData.sharedInstance().ListName);
                SharedData.sharedInstance().CubicValue = al.get(position).get("c_cubic_feet").toString();
                Log.v("CubicValue",SharedData.sharedInstance().CubicValue);
                SharedData.sharedInstance().strListName = "ListItemView";



                
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            v.getContext().startActivity(intent);


            }
        }
    });

    
    holder.increment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int count=0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            count = Integer.valueOf(holder.qtyvalue.getText().toString());
            count = count+1;
            holder.qtyvalue.setText(String.valueOf(count));
            Log.d("Plus Btn", "Clicked");
        }
    });
    holder.decrement.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int count=0;
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            count = Integer.valueOf(holder.qtyvalue.getText().toString());
            count = count-1;
            holder.qtyvalue.setText(String.valueOf(count));


        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

}

item_rowview_plus.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/root_RelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#E6E6E6" >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_listItems"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qty_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/decrement_btn"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:text="Qty"


        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/qty_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.02"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/increment_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/button_plus_normal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/decrement_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button_minus_normal"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:cropToPadding="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop = "23dp"
        android:background="@drawable/common_listview_arrow_right"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Can you please tell how to fix the bugs.

Comment: Save your increment and decrement value in your model, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time you click plus/minus

Comment: Thanks for your response, i am new to android can you please tell me how to save model. If i click plus button multiple row value added.